# How can I make nautilus like this always?

Tags: nautilus, 15.10, root

Here is my nautilus opened with `sudo nautilus`:

[image: sudo nautilus]

Here is my nautilus normally opened:

[image: normal nautilus]

I want to make nautilus always like `sudo nautilus`. *How can I do it?*
Thanks!

Comment: Don't use sudo, use gksudo instead.

Comment: when I use gksudo, nautilus's theme is corrupting. Changing to white contrast theme :(

Comment: @Dorian don't tell people to use gksu{do}. Using pain sudo is the correct way to run things as root.

Comment: @eminfedar I presume your question isn't about how to always have nautilus have root permissions, but how to have the menu bar always displayed internally, rather than in the title bar or global top panel?

Comment: @dobey Some reading for you before telling people not to say things : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo

Comment: @Dorian That information is outdated. Plain sudo or pkexec are the tools which should be used now.

Comment: @dobey He's using 15.10.

Comment: @Dorian Yes, and that information was outdated for like 13.10. Also, I'm pretty sure that is not what is being asked here. Look at the screenshots and read the question again, and read my answer. The question has nothing to do with sudo.

Comment: @dobey You are right! I'm talking about title bar, not root permissions (root permissions may also be good :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 'nautilus' to the list for the *blacklist* key under *com.canonical.unity-gtk-module* in dconf.

```
# gsettings set com.canonical.unity-gtk-module blacklist "['nautilus']"
```

This will force the menu bar to be shown inside the window, and not integrated into the title bar or top panel.

Comment: Thanks for your helps but, It doesn't change anything I tried now. Should I restart pc or something like that? I think it must work :S ?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes. Nautilus will need to be restarted after. It keeps crashing on me, so it wasn't running already when I tested it on my machine. :)